# iphone - How to control images for Retina Display?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, retina-display

My app will download a image and display it into a UIImageView.

The image is quite large, say 600 * 600 and the UIImageView's size is 100 * 100. 
So when the image is displayed, I set the UIImageView to scale it to fit.

My question is

For iPhone 3Gs, I understand the image is scaled to 100 * 100 directly and displayed in UIImageView.

But what about iPhone 4? When I do imageView.image = image, will iOS automatically scale the image to 200 * 200 first and then display it in 100 * 100 imageView?

I mean should I do anything extra to make sure that the Retina display is adapted?

Thanks

Comment: You should scale it to twice the resolution of the original for displaying t in the iPhone 4

Comment: @iphonefreak This would only hold true if the size of the image were equal or less than that of the `UIImageView`. Since in this case the image is actually larger than both the standard size (100 x 100) and the Retina size (200 x 200) nothing needs to be done to the image itself.

Comment: Do your users a favor and download an appropiately sized image from the server straight away. Will be faster and possibly cheaper. Trust the OS to do the right thing w.r.t. scaling the image to the correct number of pixels for your display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, no, you needn't do anything particular. If your UIImageView is well configured (scale to fit, as it seems you've done), an iPhone4 will display your image scaled at 200x200 pixels in a 100x100 points UIImageView. No need either to download a different "whatever@2x.png" image.

Comment: Don't forget that even if you don't own an actual iPhone4, you can test that on the Simulator by changing your device in the Hardware menu (or is it Device, I don't know, I've got a French version here).

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do anything specific here. Your image will be scaled appropriately by UIKit and in fact it's the `UIImageView` which will be affected by the Retina display, not your image. You specify a size of 100 x 100 which on non-Retina displays will hold true, but on Retina displays under the surface the physical size will actually be 200 x 200 because it'll take into account the `scaleFactor`.

Either way, the `UIImageView` will scale the image accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I marked Cyrille's answer as correct one because he answered a bit earlier than you did? tell me if you think yours came earlier. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have an experience that it works opposite way..so scale it for retina and iphone 3G or 3GS will display it correctly.